Angular ActivateRoute.Snapshot.params out of sync with URL address bar
My activatedroute.snapshot.params['id'], keeps showing an old id, when I've navigate to an entity with a different id.
The url address changes to reflect the new id, but activatedroute does not. So all my router links, on the page point to the wrong href address (since they are based on the content of activated route)
My component code
<div class="fadeIn">

      <!-- navigation menu -->
      <app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation> - activated route here doesn't match the id in the URL address bar

      <!-- page router -->
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>

Route paths
Entity gets loaded at the following route
  {
    path: 'entity/:id',
    title: 'App | Entity Details',
    loadChildren: () => import('../entity-parent/entity-parent.routes').then((m) => m.ENTITY_ROUTES),

  },

ActivatedRoute
Running this in the parent works fine, it changes to match the address bar, as I'd expect.
console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'])

But the child template, inside the parent
<app-project-navigation></app-project-navigation> 

, if I run the same code, I get the wrong result
Surely each time I naviate to a new entity/:id, when the entity component gets loaded, the activatedroute.snapshot.params would also change correctly in the parent (as it does), but any child of the parent too?
Here is more proof the issue in the child (app-project-navigation):

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.router.url)
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']) --> the observable version of this returns the same result

  }

Are just returning different results, and routerLink looks like it references to activatedRoute, so simple relative link referencing, like this doesn't work
<li>
  <a routerLink="./contracts" routerLinkActive="active">
    CONTRACTS
  </a>
</li>

UPDATE
My stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ki6sdw?file=src%2Fmain.ts
FINAL UPDATE
This was note a activeRoute.snapshot issue, since the component gets destroyed, created each time it is loaded - whether the user manually changes the id in the address bar, or navigates to a new project via the app. So it using the observable version was not needed (it gave the same wrong result anyway)
This turned out to be a bug in Angular 17..., and seems to have been fixed in Angular 18.0
Full chain of debugging this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/55776

if the issue is on the navigation menu, then we need the app-project-navigation component code. Ensure this component has the right dependencies and imports from the router modules, activated routes...

There is a much cleaner way to obtain params from a route, without ever having to touch activatedRoute:
// app.config

 provideRouter(APP_ROUTES, withComponentInputBinding()),


// APP_ROUTES

  {
    path: AppRouting.PATH.DETAIL + '/:myNamedId',
    component: MyDetailComponent       
  },

// MyDetailComponent.ts

@Input() myNamedId: string


As this is a standard input binding you can listen for changes in ngOnChanges.

This might be cleaner looking but not cleaner at all. In order to get parameters at some single place you are modifying the whole application behavior.

Ok my dude, each to their own. In my opinion this is by far a better solution than writing a param subscription per component that needs to access it. I already used named parameters in my route definitions and so leveraging component input binding from the angular/router package makes a lot of sense to me. It has zero side effects and does exactly what I need in a non-verbose manner.  Horses for courses mate!

When you change the route, with just params change, the component does not reload (ngOnInit does not fire), to handle this scenario, we have the observable version of params, that you can subscribe and will get called, when the parameter changes, so that we can handle this scenario!
We need to unsubscribe this subscription, here I use takeUntilDestroyed and destroyRef
private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);
...

...
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed(destroyRef)).subscribe((params: Params) => {
        const id = params?.id;
        // run the code of ngOnInit inside the below function, to initialize anytime parameter changes!
        initialize();
    }
}
...


It's so strange. I do this in the parent component,   console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']), and it works with no issues, i.e. it actually changes to match the URL address. But the same code (snapshot or observable version) in the  , sitting right inside the parent, returns the wrong id...

@Sachin the content in the router outlet is where the URL is a part of, if we use it outside of router-outlet, it will log the value of the parent route or root component, which ever parent component you use the component on!

Exactly, since I'm not using parent outlet, I'm wondering why it doesn't log the same output as the parent (which is showing the correct output)

@Sachin maybe the code mentioned above should be on the parent instead of the child? require a stackblitz to validate in depth this issue

It seems like you're expecting the activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id'] to update automatically when you navigate to a new id. However, the snapshot property is immutable and provides a static view of the route information at the time the component was created.
To access the current route parameters, you should use the activatedRoute.params observable instead. This observable emits a new value whenever the route parameters change. Here's how you can modify your component code to use the params observable:
for example.
export class YourComponent {

  id!: number;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
    });
  }
}


In order to get the id from the url params whenever you navigate to the component or id changes, you have to subscribe to activatedRoute.params because the ngOnInit() only fires once:
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

    private id: number;
    private destroyed$ = new Subject<boolean>();

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){}

    ngOnInit(): void {    
        this.activatedRoute.queryParams.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subscribe((params) => {
            this.id = params['id'];
  
            if (this.id) {
                // do something
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroyed$.next(true);
        this.destroyed$.unsubscribe();
    }

}


FINAL UPDATE
This was note a activeRoute.snapshot issue, since the component gets destroyed, created each time it is loaded - whether the user manually changes the id in the address bar, or navigates to a new project via the app. So using the observable version was not needed (it gave the same wrong result anyway)
This turned out to be a bug in Angular 17..., and seems to have been fixed in Angular 18.0
Full chain of debugging this here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/55776
